# difficalty to save traceroute output in shell variable?

Tags: shell, shell-script, ls, environment-variables, traceroute

I need to filter and store `traceroute` output in shell variable (array). But I am getting some unusual output.

As I try to explain in following lines.

My present directory is `temp`, having some files:

```
/temp$ ls 
ask.html  data_dump (2)  DB-Assignemnt .sql
```

When I run `traceroute` on command line its output is correct as I desired.

```
/temp$ traceroute -m 5 www.google.com  | awk '{print  $2 , $3}'
to www.google.com
172.22.0.1 (172.22.0.1)
ABTS-North-Static-085.3.160.122.airtelbroadband.in (122.160.3.85)
* *
203.101.83.197 (203.101.83.197)
182.79.254.249 (182.79.254.249
```

If I save output in a variable `a`

`/temp$ a=$(traceroute -m 5 www.google.com  | awk '{print  $2 , $3}')`

When I `echo $a` The output is not understood to me.

> ~/temp$ echo $a
>   to www.google.com 172.22.0.1 (172.22.0.1)
>   ABTS-North-Static-
>   085.3.160.122.airtelbroadband.in (122.160.3.85) ask.html data_dump (2)      DB-Assignemnt .sql **ask.html data_dump (2) DB-Assignemnt .sql
>   ask.html   data_dump (2) DB-Assignemnt .sql ask.html data_dump (2)
>   DB-Assignemnt .sql**
>   203.101.100.186 (203.101.100.186)

Why `ls` executed itself and input is save in variable `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `echo $a`, the shell does "word splitting" and all significant whitespace is lost.

Try `echo "$a"` with double quotes.

Quoting will also ensure filename expansion does not occur.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

Comment: I work done! thanks ...And understood the reason.

Comment: @Mat I was unaware to the concept `filename expansion`

Comment: @Mat: `for i in *;do echo $i;done;` `i` file  is due to  filename expansion ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: the shell assigns values to `i` based on the result of filename expansion of `*`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, you should make it a habit of always quoting variables (`echo "$i"`) -- unless you have a  specific reason for using the word splitting and other effects of not quoting.

Comment: @glennjackman , Mat Yes, now concept is clear ..thanks to all of you.